# Entity Framework Database First - How to prevent running the initial migration?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, migration, ef-database-first

I was able to scaffold an existing database using EF Core recently. We want to completely migrate to EF Core, but we've hit some snags and I need your help.

We began by running the scaffold command and ended up with this file structure

```
C:\>ls .\EFCore
Context
Models
EFCore.csproj
```

Then after creatinng the Context and the Models, I ran the inital migration command.

```
dotnet ef migrations add CreateDb
```

After running that command our directories look like this

```
C:\>ls .\EFCore
Context
Models
Migrations
EFCore.csproj

C:\>ls .\EFCore\Migrations
20210616210256_CreateDb.cs
20210616210256_CreateDb.Designer.cs
DbContextModelSnapshot.cs
```

**My Problem**

The database is already created in all environments, so we don't want entity to execute the inital database migration. Should I delete `20210616210256_CreateDb.cs` and `20210616210256_CreateDb.Designer.cs` to achieve this?

The other route I can think of is create the `__EFMigrationsHistory` table and insert a row into it. This would fake that we've already ran the inital db create.

Help please, I would like to do this the cleanest way possible.

Comment: You title (and tag) says you want 'database first', but you are executing commands for code first, i.e.: telling EF to update your database from code, not the other way around. Am i confused or are you? ;)

Comment: @nilsK I'm confused? We have an existing database with tons of tables and fields, and the scaffold command generates models and context based on that. Then I need to generate the snapshot so entity understands that those migrations already have "been run"

Answer (score 1):

Remove/Comment the code inside your Up() and Down() methods of migration file and call update database. You don't want the code which creates table i.e.

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.YourTable",
            c => new
                { //Properties set here })
```

Your migration class could look like this -

```
public partial class Initial : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {   
    }
    
    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```